# Create Custom Dynamic Prototype Cells programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell

I am having an issue trying to create Dynamic Prototype Cells programmatically.  This is my first time trying this approach.  I have always created them through storyboard.

I have my ViewController.swift file which contains the following

```
var noteListTableView: UITableView = UITableView()

noteListTableView.frame.origin.x = 0.0
noteListTableView.frame.origin.y = kNAV_BAR_HEIGHT
noteListTableView.frame.size.width = kDEVICE_WIDTH
noteListTableView.frame.size.height = kDEVICE_HEIGHT - kNAV_BAR_HEIGHT
noteListTableView.dataSource = self
noteListTableView.delegate = self
self.view.addSubview(noteListTableView)
```

Also in the file, I have included the appropriate TableView delegate and Data source functions

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return GlobalDataController.notesDB.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var aNote: NoteItem = GlobalDataController.notesDB[indexPath.row] as NoteItem

    if var cell: NoteListTVCell = noteListTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(kReuseCellNoteList) as? NoteListTVCell {

        cell.noteTitle.text = "Title"
        cell.noteContentSummary.text = "Content Summary"
        cell.noteDate.text = "May 20"

            return cell
        }
    else{

        var cell: NoteListTVCell = NoteListTVCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: kReuseCellNoteList)

        cell.noteTitle.text = "Title"
        cell.noteContentSummary.text = "Content Summary"
        cell.noteDate.text = "May 20"

        return cell
    }
}
```

(1) The IF-STATEMENT always seems to fail, that is why I added the else statement as per some example I found online for Obj-C.

(2) When the ELSE is triggered, the program always crashes trying to assign the cell.* values, saying it encountered a nil value.

EDIT: NoteListTVCell

```
class NoteListTVCell: UITableViewCell {

    var noteTitle: UILabel!
    var noteContentSummary: UILabel!
    var noteDate: UILabel!

    var cellMargin: CGFloat = kPadding * 3

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        noteTitle = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: cellMargin, y: kPadding, width: kDEVICE_WIDTH - cellMargin - kPadding, height: 30.0))
        noteTitle.backgroundColor = kColorTransparent
        noteTitle.font = UIFont(name: kFont02, size: 20.0)
        noteTitle.textColor = Scripts.hexColor(0x000000, alpha: 0.8)
        noteTitle.text = "Title"
        self.addSubview(noteTitle)

        /* Note Content Summary
        -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        var noteContentSummaryY: CGFloat = noteTitle.frame.origin.y + noteTitle.frame.size.height

        noteContentSummary = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: cellMargin, y: noteContentSummaryY, width: kDEVICE_WIDTH - cellMargin - kPadding, height: 20.0))
        noteContentSummary.backgroundColor = kColorTransparent
        noteContentSummary.font = UIFont(name: kFont02, size: 14.0)
        noteContentSummary.textColor = Scripts.hexColor(0x000000, alpha: 0.4)
        noteContentSummary.text = "This is a summary..."
        self.addSubview(noteContentSummary)

        /* Note Date
        -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        noteDate = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: kDEVICE_WIDTH - 100.0 - kPaddingx2, y: kPadding, width: 100.0, height: 20.0))
        noteDate.backgroundColor = kColorTransparent
        noteDate.font = UIFont(name: kFont02, size: 10.0)
        noteDate.textColor = Scripts.hexColor(kColorThemeBlue, alpha: 1.0)
        noteDate.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Right
        noteDate.text = "May 8, 2:14 AM"
        self.addSubview(noteDate)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post NoteListTVCell class. Also create the table like                 var noteListTableView: UITableView = UITableView(frame: frame, style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)

Comment: @Amit89 I've added the Class as you requested.  Also, I quickly tried your suggestion on initializing the TableView...I'm still getting the same error. fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't override the init method in your custom cell, but anyway it will call super init method, if you don't provide. Put your cell initialisation code in init method instead of awakeFromNib method.

Try this below.

```
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

            super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }


    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!) {

         super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
         //Do your cell set up
        noteTitle = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: cellMargin, y: kPadding, width: kDEVICE_WIDTH - cellMargin - kPadding, height: 30.0))
        noteTitle.backgroundColor = kColorTransparent
        noteTitle.font = UIFont(name: kFont02, size: 20.0)
        noteTitle.textColor = Scripts.hexColor(0x000000, alpha: 0.8)
        noteTitle.text = "Title"
        self.addSubview(noteTitle)

        /* Note Content Summary
        -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        var noteContentSummaryY: CGFloat = noteTitle.frame.origin.y + noteTitle.frame.size.height

        noteContentSummary = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: cellMargin, y: noteContentSummaryY, width: kDEVICE_WIDTH - cellMargin - kPadding, height: 20.0))
        noteContentSummary.backgroundColor = kColorTransparent
        noteContentSummary.font = UIFont(name: kFont02, size: 14.0)
        noteContentSummary.textColor = Scripts.hexColor(0x000000, alpha: 0.4)
        noteContentSummary.text = "This is a summary..."
        self.addSubview(noteContentSummary)

        /* Note Date
        -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        noteDate = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: kDEVICE_WIDTH - 100.0 - kPaddingx2, y: kPadding, width: 100.0, height: 20.0))
        noteDate.backgroundColor = kColorTransparent
        noteDate.font = UIFont(name: kFont02, size: 10.0)
        noteDate.textColor = Scripts.hexColor(kColorThemeBlue, alpha: 1.0)
        noteDate.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Right
        noteDate.text = "May 8, 2:14 AM"
        self.addSubview(noteDate)
    }
```

Do this in viewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        noteListTableView = UITableView(frame: self.view.frame, style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
        noteListTableView.dataSource = self
        noteListTableView.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(noteListTableView)
        noteListTableView.registerClass(NoteListTVCellTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: kReuseCellNoteList)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
```

Comment: You need to add in viewDidLoad method. notelistTableView.registerClass(NoteListTVCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: kReuseCellNoteList)

Comment: Thank you @Amit89!!! Just finished implementing those changes and that did it.  The overriding of the init method which I was missing seems to be the main culprit.  I was able to get this to run now!!

Comment: Nice to help you. If it helped you can up vote so it will help others too.

Comment: Excellent point, will do.  Thanks a lot, I was struggling with that.  It was the only thing I had left to get it all working.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register your custom tableViewCell class in `viewDidLoad`:

```
notelistTableView.registerClass(NoteListTVCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: kReuseCellNoteList)
```

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:)

When designing the prototype in InterfaceBuilder this is done automatically. It is required when you design your cell in code.

Comment: I initially had that, but removed based on a comment I saw in another forum, because my program was crashing.  I put it back again to test and still the same issue, it is still crashing.